# Android exporting contact database without root permissions

Tags: android, database, copy, root, contacts

I make application. My application make copy of contact database and send this file to FTP server. In project only. I tried to copy file /data/data/android.contact.provider/databse.db, but this give my error. Help me please. Is this possible ??? Thanks,

PS
Application **can't** use root (Superuser) permissons.

Comment: what do you mean by making a copy of the contacts database? Do you mean the sqlite database file? If yes, you need root permissions to do that.

Comment: yes i want to create copy of this file, or accurate copy of database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible ?

Copying `/data/data/android.contact.provider/databse.db` is not possible. You do not have read access to that directory, except perhaps if you are running as root.

> PS Application can't use root (Superuser) permissons.

Then you cannot copy the database.

> yes i want to create copy of this file, or accurate copy of database

You are welcome to request the `READ_CONTACTS` database and query the `ContactsContract` `ContentProvider` to obtain whatever data you wish.

Comment: are any method, approach ?

Comment: help me please, it's for me important

Comment: can you help me in write this code ? PS I don't want to steal data